# Sort array of objects by a given property in numbers first, then letters (with numbers having a sub-sort)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I know how to sort by either numbers or letters, not sure how to do both.

```
sessionStorage.cart
==> "[
{"id":1, "number":1, "other_attributes":"other_values"},
{"id":2, "number":2, "other_attributes":"other_values"},
{"id":"processing", "other_attributes":"other_values"},
{"id":2, "number":1, "other_attributes":"other_values"},
{"id":"deposit", "other_attributes":"other_values"}
]"
```

I would like to sort the cart by `id`, where the following applies:

- first show me all the items where `id` is an integer
- then show me all the items where `id` is a string
- where `id` is an integer, if multiple items have the same integer, sort by `number`
- where `id` is a string, sort alphabetically

The end result of the example above should be (after JSON parsing, and setting back to `sessionStorage`)

```
==> "[
{"id":1, "number":1, "other_attributes":"other_values"},
{"id":2, "number":1, "other_attributes":"other_values"},
{"id":2, "number":2, "other_attributes":"other_values"},
{"id":"deposit", "other_attributes":"other_values"},
{"id":"processing", "other_attributes":"other_values"},
]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** with custom sorting function

```js
var arr = [{
  "id": 1,
  "number": 1,
  "other_attributes": "other_values"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "number": 2,
  "other_attributes": "other_values"
}, {
  "id": "processing",
  "other_attributes": "other_values"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "number": 1,
  "other_attributes": "other_values"
}, {
  "id": "deposit",
  "other_attributes": "other_values"
}];

arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  // check both id's are number
  if (typeof a.id == 'number' && typeof b.id == 'number') {
    // check both are equal
    if (a.id == b.id)
      // if equal sort based on `number`
      return a.numer - b.number
    // else sort based on id  
    return a.id - b.id
    // check first one is number
  } else if (typeof a.id == 'number')
    // since number have higher sort order return -1
    return -1;
  // check second one is number
  else if (typeof b.id == 'number')
    // since string have lower sort order return 1
    return 1;
  // in case both are string
  else {
    // return based on string comaprison
    if (a.id > b.id)
      return 1;
    else if (a.id < b.id)
      return -1
    return 0;
  }
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Typo here: ` if (typeof a.id == 'number' && typeof a.id == 'number') {`

Comment: 2nd typeof should be `typeof b.id`

Comment: quick typo but this is great thanks! `return a.numer - b.number` should be `a.number`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to sort twice

**DEMO**

```js
    var arr = [
    {"id":1, "number":1, "other_attributes":"other_values"},
    {"id":2, "number":2, "other_attributes":"other_values"},
    {"id":"processing", "other_attributes":"other_values"},
    {"id":2, "number":1, "other_attributes":"other_values"},
    {"id":"deposit", "other_attributes":"other_values"}
    ]
    arr.sort(function(a,b){ var numa = a.number || Number.MAX_VALUE; var numb = b.number || Number.MAX_VALUE; return numa - numb; });
    arr.sort(function(a,b){ return a.id - b.id  });
    document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(arr,1,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
var cart = [
  {"id":1, "number":1, "other_attributes":"other_values"},
  {"id":2, "number":2, "other_attributes":"other_values"},
  {"id":"processing", "other_attributes":"other_values"},
  {"id":2, "number":1, "other_attributes":"other_values"},
  {"id":"deposit", "other_attributes":"other_values"}
];

function makeComparator(identifier) {
  return function compare(a,b) {
    a = a[identifier];
    b = b[identifier];

    if (Number.isInteger(a) && Number.isInteger(b) ) {
      return a > b;
    }

    if (Number.isInteger(a)) {
      return -1;
    }

    if (Number.isInteger(b)) {
      return 1;
    }

    return a > b;
  }
}

var idComparator = makeComparator("id");
var numberComparator = makeComparator("number");

cart.sort(idComparator);
cart.sort(numberComparator);
console.log(cart);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(cart, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the same as the above, but I like indents :)  Also takes advantage of the fact that id is either only a string or an integer to use localeCompare

```
var cart = [
{"id":1, "number":1, "other_attributes":"other_values"},
{"id":2, "number":2, "other_attributes":"other_values"},
{"id":"processing", "other_attributes":"other_values"},
{"id":2, "number":1, "other_attributes":"other_values"},
{"id":"deposit", "other_attributes":"other_values"}
];

function compareCart(a, b) {
    if (typeof a.id == 'number') {
        if (typeof b.id == 'number') {
            if (a.id == b.id) {
                return a.number - b.number;
            }
            return a.id - b.id;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    if (typeof b.id == 'number') {
        return 1;
    }
    return a.id.localeCompare(b.id);
}

cart.sort(compareCart);
console.log(cart);
```

Comment: not sure what `localeCompare` is, i'm looking it up, right now this is returning an error `Uncaught TypeError: a.id.localeCompare is not a function`

Comment: yeah, tried to be smart and use Number.isInteger and it didn't work.  typeof does

Comment: @james localeCompare is only defined on strings (which is why it was giving the error earlier)

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript `sort` function & `ternary operator` to achieve this. This is basically multilevel sorting.

**Brief explanation**

If we consider `id` it will take first two id which we are passing and compare them if they are unequal.
Here "?" is the condition checker which will check if they are greater or lesser than one another and return 1 or -1. 1 will return ascending order & -1 will return it in descending order. When both id(s) are equal it will check this condition

```
a.number>b.number?1:a.number<b.number?-1:0
```

"0" mean it will return nothing if both are equal.If `number` are equal you can expand the depth of sorting to `"other_attributes"` by expanding the ternary operator.

I have added few more value just to check the gene-unity of the sorting.

```
var a = [
{"id":1, "number":1, "other_attributes":"other_values"},
{"id":2, "number":3, "other_attributes":"other_values"},
{"id":2, "number":2, "other_attributes":"other_values"},
{"id":"processing", "other_attributes":"other_values"},
{"id":2, "number":1, "other_attributes":"other_values"},
{"id":"deposit", "other_attributes":"other_values"},
{"id":1, "number":10, "other_attributes":"other_values"}
]
var b = a.sort(function(a,b){

   return a.id.toString() >b.id.toString() ?1:a.id.toString()<b.id.toString()?-1:a.number>b.number?1:a.number<b.number?-1:0
})
console.log(b)
```

[CHECK HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/jhrno4gf/)